# Errors with Dockerfile of Nighres Project (error with setup.py bdist_wheel for JCC python 3.7,...)

Tags: docker, signal-processing, ubuntu-16.04, python-3.7

I am trying to install and use nighres from https://nighres.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
I started by the docker image installation image.
Below you find a link for my modified version of Dockerfile:
https://github.com/marsup13/MyStruggleWithAIM/blob/main/Dockerfile

I have made a lot of changes in the original Dockerfile (python version mainly).

The problem I have faced is when executing the following command from Dockerfile:

```
RUN sudo apt-get install -y jcc && \
    python3.7 -m pip install --upgrade pip \
                                     wheel \
                                     JCC \
                                     urllib3 \
                                     jupyter \
                          nilearn \
                          sklearn \
                          nose \
                          matplotlib \
                          scipy
```

I got these errors (I am using Docker on Ubuntu 20.04).

```
Building wheels for collected packages: JCC, sklearn, pandocfilters, argon2-cffi, pyrsistent
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for JCC: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for JCC: finished with status 'error'
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-5ffcvkyp/JCC/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpwvntxw0ypip-wheel- --python-tag cp37:
  Failed building wheel for JCC
  Applied shared mode monkeypatch to: <module 'setuptools' from '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py'>
  Loading source files for package org.apache.jcc...
  Constructing Javadoc information...
  Standard Doclet version 1.8.0_282
  Building tree for all the packages and classes...
  Generating javadoc/org/apache/jcc/PythonException.html...
  Generating javadoc/org/apache/jcc/PythonVM.html...
  Generating javadoc/org/apache/jcc/package-frame.html...
  Generating javadoc/org/apache/jcc/package-summary.html...
  Generating javadoc/org/apache/jcc/package-tree.html...
  Generating javadoc/constant-values.html...
  Generating javadoc/serialized-form.html...
  Building index for all the packages and classes...
  Generating javadoc/overview-tree.html...
  Generating javadoc/index-all.html...
  Generating javadoc/deprecated-list.html...
  Building index for all classes...
  Generating javadoc/allclasses-frame.html...
  Generating javadoc/allclasses-noframe.html...
  Generating javadoc/index.html...
  Generating javadoc/help-doc.html...
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  writing /tmp/pip-build-5ffcvkyp/JCC/jcc3/config.py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/jcc
  ...
  copying jcc3/classes/org/apache/jcc/PythonVM.class -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/jcc/classes/org/apache/jcc
  copying jcc3/classes/org/apache/jcc/PythonException.class -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/jcc/classes/org/apache/jcc
  running build_ext
  building 'jcc3' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/jcc3
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/jcc3/sources
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -D_jcc_lib -DJCC_VER="3.8" -I/docker-java-home/include -I/docker-java-home/include/linux -I_jcc3 -Ijcc3/sources -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c jcc3/sources/jcc.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/jcc3/sources/jcc.o -DPYTHON -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-write-strings
  jcc3/sources/jcc.cpp:25:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
  
  ----------------------------------------
  Running setup.py clean for JCC
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for sklearn: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for sklearn: finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/76/03/bb/589d421d27431bcd2c6da284d5f2286c8e3b2ea3cf1594c074
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pandocfilters: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pandocfilters: finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/93/9a/79/b2c3567908fd6209e4674ca23d9fcf005aae5fe89148913727
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for argon2-cffi: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for argon2-cffi: finished with status 'error'
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-5ffcvkyp/argon2-cffi/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmp4c5jlxxfpip-wheel- --python-tag cp37:
  c/_cffi_backend.c:2:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
  compilation terminated.
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/unixccompiler.py", line 118, in _compile
      extra_postargs)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 910, in spawn
      spawn(cmd, dry_run=self.dry_run)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/spawn.py", line 36, in spawn
      _spawn_posix(cmd, search_path, dry_run=dry_run)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/spawn.py", line 159, in _spawn_posix
      % (cmd, exit_status))
  distutils.errors.DistutilsExecError: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
  
  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
  
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 161, in run
      cmd = self.call_command('install_lib', warn_dir=0)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 147, in call_command
      self.run_command(cmdname)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install_lib.py", line 23, in run
      self.build()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/install_lib.py", line 109, in build
      self.run_command('build_ext')
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 49, in run
      _build_ext.run(self)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 340, in run
      self.build_extensions()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 449, in build_extensions
      self._build_extensions_serial()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 474, in _build_extensions_serial
      self.build_extension(ext)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 174, in build_extension
      _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 534, in build_extension
      depends=ext.depends)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 574, in compile
      self._compile(obj, src, ext, cc_args, extra_postargs, pp_opts)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/unixccompiler.py", line 120, in _compile
      raise CompileError(msg)
  distutils.errors.CompileError: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
  
  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
  
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
      yield saved
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
      yield
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 243, in run_setup
      DirectorySandbox(setup_dir).run(runner)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 273, in run
      return func()
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 242, in runner
      _execfile(setup_script, ns)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 46, in _execfile
      exec(code, globals, locals)
    File "/tmp/easy_install-nhryt98i/cffi-1.14.5/setup.py", line 238, in <module>
      """
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/core.py", line 163, in setup
      raise SystemExit("error: " + str(msg))
  SystemExit: error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
  
  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
  
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1087, in run_setup
      run_setup(setup_script, args)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 246, in run_setup
      raise
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py", line 130, in __exit__
      self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
      yield
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py", line 130, in __exit__
      self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 166, in save_modules
      saved_exc.resume()
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 141, in resume
      six.reraise(type, exc, self._tb)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/six.py", line 685, in reraise
      raise value.with_traceback(tb)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
      yield saved
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
      yield
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 243, in run_setup
      DirectorySandbox(setup_dir).run(runner)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 273, in run
      return func()
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 242, in runner
      _execfile(setup_script, ns)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 46, in _execfile
      exec(code, globals, locals)
    File "/tmp/easy_install-nhryt98i/cffi-1.14.5/setup.py", line 238, in <module>
      """
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/core.py", line 163, in setup
      raise SystemExit("error: " + str(msg))
  SystemExit: error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
  
  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
  
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-build-5ffcvkyp/argon2-cffi/setup.py", line 387, in <module>
      **keywords_with_side_effects(sys.argv)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/core.py", line 108, in setup
      _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 269, in __init__
      self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 313, in fetch_build_eggs
      replace_conflicting=True,
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 826, in resolve
      dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1092, in best_match
      return self.obtain(req, installer)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1104, in obtain
      return installer(requirement)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 380, in fetch_build_egg
      return cmd.easy_install(req)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 663, in easy_install
      return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 693, in install_item
      dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 873, in install_eggs
      return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1101, in build_and_install
      self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1089, in run_setup
      raise DistutilsError("Setup script exited with %s" % (v.args[0],))
  distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
  
  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for argon2-cffi
  Running setup.py clean for argon2-cffi
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-5ffcvkyp/argon2-cffi/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" clean --all:
  c/_cffi_backend.c:2:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
  compilation terminated.
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/unixccompiler.py", line 118, in _compile
      extra_postargs)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 910, in spawn
      spawn(cmd, dry_run=self.dry_run)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/spawn.py", line 36, in spawn
      _spawn_posix(cmd, search_path, dry_run=dry_run)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/spawn.py", line 159, in _spawn_posix
      % (cmd, exit_status))
  distutils.errors.DistutilsExecError: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
  
  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
  
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 161, in run
      cmd = self.call_command('install_lib', warn_dir=0)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 147, in call_command
      self.run_command(cmdname)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install_lib.py", line 23, in run
      self.build()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/install_lib.py", line 109, in build
      self.run_command('build_ext')
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 49, in run
      _build_ext.run(self)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 340, in run
      self.build_extensions()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 449, in build_extensions
      self._build_extensions_serial()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 474, in _build_extensions_serial
      self.build_extension(ext)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 174, in build_extension
      _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 534, in build_extension
      depends=ext.depends)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 574, in compile
      self._compile(obj, src, ext, cc_args, extra_postargs, pp_opts)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/unixccompiler.py", line 120, in _compile
      raise CompileError(msg)
  distutils.errors.CompileError: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
  
  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
  
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
      yield saved
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
      yield
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 243, in run_setup
      DirectorySandbox(setup_dir).run(runner)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 273, in run
      return func()
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 242, in runner
      _execfile(setup_script, ns)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 46, in _execfile
      exec(code, globals, locals)
    File "/tmp/easy_install-dtvehjsg/cffi-1.14.5/setup.py", line 238, in <module>
      """
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/core.py", line 163, in setup
      raise SystemEx  Failed cleaning build dir for argon2-cffi
it("error: " + str(msg))
  SystemExit: error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
  
  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
  
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1087, in run_setup
      run_setup(setup_script, args)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 246, in run_setup
      raise
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py", line 130, in __exit__
      self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
      yield
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py", line 130, in __exit__
      self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 166, in save_modules
      saved_exc.resume()
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 141, in resume
      six.reraise(type, exc, self._tb)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/six.py", line 685, in reraise
      raise value.with_traceback(tb)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
      yield saved
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
      yield
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 243, in run_setup
      DirectorySandbox(setup_dir).run(runner)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 273, in run
      return func()
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 242, in runner
      _execfile(setup_script, ns)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 46, in _execfile
      exec(code, globals, locals)
    File "/tmp/easy_install-dtvehjsg/cffi-1.14.5/setup.py", line 238, in <module>
      """
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/core.py", line 163, in setup
      raise SystemExit("error: " + str(msg))
  SystemExit: error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
  
  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
  
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-build-5ffcvkyp/argon2-cffi/setup.py", line 387, in <module>
      **keywords_with_side_effects(sys.argv)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/core.py", line 108, in setup
      _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 269, in __init__
      self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 313, in fetch_build_eggs
      replace_conflicting=True,
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 826, in resolve
      dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1092, in best_match
      return self.obtain(req, installer)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1104, in obtain
      return installer(requirement)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 380, in fetch_build_egg
      return cmd.easy_install(req)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 663, in easy_install
      return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 693, in install_item
      dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 873, in install_eggs
      return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1101, in build_and_install
      self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1089, in run_setup
      raise DistutilsError("Setup script exited with %s" % (v.args[0],))
  distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
  
  ----------------------------------------
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pyrsistent: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pyrsistent: finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/f0/b8/de/b593ad311be4eb458499d100db081e453576032272398b7ddc
Successfully built sklearn pandocfilters pyrsistent
Failed to build JCC argon2-cffi
Installing collected packages: pip, wheel, JCC, urllib3, tornado, backcall, pickleshare, pygments, wcwidth, prompt-toolkit, parso, jedi, ipython-genutils, traitlets, ptyprocess, pexpect, decorator, setuptools, ipython, six, python-dateutil, pyzmq, jupyter-core, jupyter-client, ipykernel, jupyterlab-widgets, attrs, zipp, typing-extensions, importlib-metadata, pyrsistent, jsonschema, nbformat, terminado, prometheus-client, Send2Trash, MarkupSafe, jinja2, pycparser, cffi, enum34, argon2-cffi, async-generator, nest-asyncio, nbclient, jupyterlab-pygments, entrypoints, webencodings, pyparsing, packaging, bleach, pandocfilters, mistune, testpath, defusedxml, nbconvert, notebook, widgetsnbextension, ipywidgets, qtpy, qtconsole, jupyter-console, jupyter, joblib, idna, chardet, certifi, requests, numpy, scipy, threadpoolctl, scikit-learn, nibabel, pytz, pandas, nilearn, sklearn, nose, kiwisolver, cycler, pillow, matplotlib
  Found existing installation: pip 8.1.1
    Not uninstalling pip at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
  Found existing installation: wheel 0.29.0
    Not uninstalling wheel at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
  Running setup.py install for JCC: started
    Running setup.py install for JCC: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-5ffcvkyp/JCC/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-b9bi3lz7-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    Applied shared mode monkeypatch to: <module 'setuptools' from '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py'>
    Loading source files for package org.apache.jcc...
    Constructing Javadoc information...
    Standard Doclet version 1.8.0_282
    Building tree for all the packages and classes...
    Generating javadoc/org/apache/jcc/PythonException.html...
    Generating javadoc/org/apache/jcc/PythonVM.html...
    Generating javadoc/org/apache/jcc/package-frame.html...
    Generating javadoc/org/apache/jcc/package-summary.html...
    Generating javadoc/org/apache/jcc/package-tree.html...
    Generating javadoc/constant-values.html...
    Generating javadoc/serialized-form.html...
    Building index for all the packages and classes...
    Generating javadoc/overview-tree.html...
    Generating javadoc/index-all.html...
    Generating javadoc/deprecated-list.html...
    Building index for all classes...
    Generating javadoc/allclasses-frame.html...
    Generating javadoc/allclasses-noframe.html...
    Generating javadoc/index.html...
    Generating javadoc/help-doc.html...
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    not writing /tmp/pip-build-5ffcvkyp/JCC/jcc3/config.py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/jcc
    copying jcc3/cpp.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/jcc
    copying jcc3/__main__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/jcc
    copying jcc3/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/jcc
    copying jcc3/windows.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/jcc
    copying jcc3/python.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/jcc
    copying jcc3/config.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/jcc
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/jcc/sources
    copying jcc3/sources/JArray.cpp -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/jcc/sources
    copying jcc3/sources/jcc.cpp -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/jcc/sources
    copying jcc3/sources/JObject.cpp -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/jcc/sources
    copying jcc3/sources/JCCEnv.cpp -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/jcc/sources
    copying jcc3/sources/types.cpp -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/jcc/sources
    copying jcc3/sources/functions.cpp -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/jcc/sources
    copying jcc3/sources/macros.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/jcc/sources
    copying jcc3/sources/functions.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/jcc/sources
    copying jcc3/sources/JObject.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/jcc/sources
    copying jcc3/sources/jccfuncs.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/jcc/sources
    copying jcc3/sources/JArray.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/jcc/sources
    copying jcc3/sources/JCCEnv.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/jcc/sources
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/jcc/classes
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/jcc/classes/org
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/jcc/classes/org/apache
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/jcc/classes/org/apache/jcc
    copying jcc3/classes/org/apache/jcc/PythonVM.class -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/jcc/classes/org/apache/jcc
    copying jcc3/classes/org/apache/jcc/PythonException.class -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/jcc/classes/org/apache/jcc
    running build_ext
    building 'jcc3' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/jcc3
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/jcc3/sources
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -D_jcc_lib -DJCC_VER="3.8" -I/docker-java-home/include -I/docker-java-home/include/linux -I_jcc3 -Ijcc3/sources -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c jcc3/sources/jcc.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/jcc3/sources/jcc.o -DPYTHON -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-write-strings
    jcc3/sources/jcc.cpp:25:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-5ffcvkyp/JCC/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-b9bi3lz7-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-5ffcvkyp/JCC/
The command '/bin/sh -c sudo apt-get install -y jcc &&     python3.7 -m pip install --upgrade pip                                      wheel                                      JCC                                      urllib3                                      jupyter                           nilearn                         sklearn                         nose                        matplotlib               scipy' returned a non-zero code: 1
```